# Python 2.7- Pygal Bar Chart import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, importerror, pygal

I downloaded and installed Pygal.

```
import pygal 
bar_chart= pygal.Bar()
```

And the error I get is

> Undefined variable from import: Bar

I am not sure what is going wrong. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this locally, and the [documentation](http://pygal.org/chart_types/#idbar-charts-histograms) says you are correct. How did you install the pygal module?

Comment: Hello Andy you are correct, I followed the documentation. I used pip install. I want to add here that I am using Windows 7, not sure if that matters.